# mongoose add more key:value inside ref field

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, populate

```
   organs: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Organ',
      healthValue: { // i want to add this field but it is becoming invalid, not generating auto with default val
        type: Number,
        default: 0,
      }
    },
  ],
```

I have a user schema and also there is **organs** key in this schema. I'm keeping organs with ref way to get belongs to user organs. I also should keep organ health value but I can not keep it in ref field together as above. How can i do this? Can not I add more key:value to populate (type & ref) fields?

Answer (score 1):

```
   organs: [
    {
      organId: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Organ',
      },
      healthValue: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0,
      },
      isOwned: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false,
      },
    },
  ],
```

i think i solve with above code block, i did use wrong syntax